# How to display a drawable according to a condition entered by the user in Android studio(Java)

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I have a list of items displayed in Recycler view and they are sorted according to their priority (1,2,3) entered by the user with 1 on top and 3 at the bottom. I want the items to be accompanied by a drawable in red(for priority 1), yellow(for priority 2) and green(for priority 3) depending on the input from the user. May I
please know how to display the drawable in such a case.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmC6n.jpg)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZeLA.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code segment of what you tried.

Comment: I have accepted the answer provided earlier. Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter or create a `bind` method in your view holder and then call it from `onBindViewHolder`

For the latter, in your view holder create bind method

In Kotlin

```
class TaskViewHolder(private val taskItemBinding: TaskItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(taskItemBinding.root) {
            fun bind(task: Task) {
                taskItemBinding.apply {
                    priorityIndicator.setImageDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                            priorityIndicator.context,
                            when (task.priority) {
                                1 -> R.drawable.indicator_red
                                2 -> R.drawable.indicator_yellow
                                3 -> R.drawable.indicator_green
                            }
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, call it from `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val task = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(task)
}
```

In Java

```
public class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView priorityIndicator;

        public TaskViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            priorityIndicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priorityIndicator);
        }


        private void bind(Task task) {
            int drawableId;
            switch (task.priority) {
                case 1: drawableId = R.drawable.indicator_red;
                    break;
                case 2: drawableId = R.drawable.indicator_yellow;
                    break;
                default: drawableId = R.drawable.indicator_green;
            }
            priorityIndicator.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(priorityIndicator.getContext(), drawableId)
            );
        }
    }
```

Now call it from `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(taskList.get(position));
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer, but can you please explain the same in Java, because I'm very new to Kotlin and it would be easier to understand in Java. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask a doubt, what are the parameters that you have taken in the bind method (Task task). Is it the List or model class or something else?

Comment: Again, sorry for the doubts but may I also know what is the mImageView in the priorityIndicator.setImageDrawable();

Comment: Actually, it is `priorityIndicator` somehow by mistake I typed it `mImageView`, Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `Task` in bind method is the single object of your model class, in which you have defined your task detail, make changes as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

So the color of the layout is always the same right? Red for 1st index, yellow for 2nd, and green for 3rd?

On your RecyclerView adapter you can pass a position parameter at `onBindViewHolder` and add condition based on the position. For example:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: listHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(listItem[position], position)
}

class ListHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(item: YourItem, position) {
        when(position){
            0 -> binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.redDrawable)
            1 -> binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowDrawable)
            2 -> binding.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenDrawable)
        }
    }
 }
```